# How to create a directory search and replace with vimscript and fzf

Tags: vim, fzf

I'm trying to create a directory search and replace function in vimscript using [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim). The place where I block is when trying to use `Alt-a` fzf binding to select the whole list. I'm not even sure if that is possible given fzf is an external process but I may be wrong.

Here's my current function.

```
function! CWDSearchAndReplace()

    " Try to get word under cursor else prompt user for a word
    let wordToReplace = expand("<cword>")
    if wordToReplace == ""
        call inputsave()
        let wordToReplace = input("Replace: ")
        call inputrestore()
    endif

    " Prompt for replacement
    call inputsave()
    let replacement = input("Replace \"" . wordToReplace . "\" with: ")
    call inputrestore()
    execute "Ag " . wordToReplace

    " =====>  Here I'd like to execute Alt-a followed by <CR>

    execute "cdo %s//" . replacement . "/gc"
end function
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where do you get that `Alt-a` from? Are you talking about [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) or [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim)? Why so many third-party tools in your function?

Comment: fzf.vim. Ag is part of fzf.vim and cdo is now part of vim. Alt-A comes from fzf.vim docs and is hardcoded because of the way fzf is used

Comment: A handy and fast way to search and replace across files is to use vim-ripgrep for searching, and quickfix-reflector to save any edits in the resulting quickfix window.

Answer (score 2):

As [pointed out](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/178) by the creator of [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim), there is no need to use `fzf` here, one can simply use `ag`.

```
function! s:ag_to_qf(line)
  let parts = split(a:line, ':')
  echo parts
  return {'filename': parts[0], 'lnum': parts[1], 'col': parts[2],
        \ 'text': join(parts[3:], ':')}
endfunction

function! AgToQF(query)
  call setqflist(map(systemlist('ag --column '.a:query), 's:ag_to_qf(v:val)'))
endfunction

function! CWDSearchAndReplace()
    let wordUnderCursor = expand("<cword>")
    call inputsave()
    let wordToReplace = input("Replace : ", wordUnderCursor)
    call inputrestore()
    call inputsave()
    let replacement = input("Replace \"" . wordUnderCursor . "\" with: ")
    call inputrestore()
    call AgToQF(wordUnderCursor)
    execute "cdo %s/" . wordToReplace . "/" . replacement ."/gc"
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>r :call FileSearchAndReplace()<CR>
```